# Why are these coefficients wrong? (Upper triangularization)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Good afternoon!

I am coming here for a quick linear algebra question, cause there is something bugging me in the upper triangularization process.

Say we have a matrix  $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$. Its eigenvalues are $0$ (with multiplicity $2$) and $2$ (with multiplicity $1$).

So consider the eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$ and a corresponding eigenvector $v = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$.

Then, we can extend $\{v\}$ to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ : $\{v, e_1, e_3\}$.

And, can show that $\{V + e_1, V + e_3\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}/V$, where $V = \text{Span}(v)$.

Now, define the map $\pi : \mathbb{R}^3/V  \to \mathbb{R}^3/V$ such that $\pi :  W + x \mapsto W + Ax$. And then:

$A' = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & * & *\\
0 & \\
0 &  
\end{pmatrix}$, where the bottom right block is the matrix $[\pi]$ with respect to the above basis. We can now compute it by noticing that:

$\pi(V + e_1) = V + Ae_1 = V + (-v + 2e_1)$.

$\pi(V + e_3) = V + Ae_3 = V + (-v + 2e_1)$.

And **now,** here is the step I believe is wrong but don't understand why:

Since $\pi(V + e_1) = V + (-v + 2e_1 + 0e_3) = \pi(V + e_3)$, I want to think that the "starred coefficients" in $A'$ above are both $-1$, since $v$ is the first vector of the "triangular basis".

But if I do so, I then find:

$A'' = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & -1\\
0 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

And, by repeating the triangularization process on the bottom right $(2\times 2)$ block, I find:

$A''' = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$, which then **should **correspond to expressing $A$ in the basis

$\{\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$}. But the thing is: it **doesn't**.

Indeed, if I adjoin those three vectors into a change of basis matrix $P$, then:

$P^{-1} A P = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$.

Which is also an upper triangular matrix with the same eigenvalues: but the coefficients above the diagonal are different!

So I am trying to figure out why my reasoning is wrong.
I apologize for the length of the question, I thought it would be clearer if I showed my reasoning with a specific example.

Thanks for your time!